# ElasticSearch: Multi_fields parameter not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a multi fields parameter "startTime", below is the mapping

```
"startTime" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "raw" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss||dd-MM-yyyy||hour_minute_second"
        }
      }
    }
```

i inserted few documents

```
{    
  "orgId" => "backendorg",
  "startTime" => "01-01-1980 06:32:51"
}
{
  "orgId" => "backendorg",
  "startTime" => "01-01-1980 06:35:51"
}
{          
  "orgId" => "backendorg",
  "startTime" => "01-01-1980 06:39:51"
}
```

when i am trying to filter startTime based on below query it is returning empty result

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "orgId": {
          "value": "backendorg",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "range": {
              "startTime": {
                "from": "01-01-1980 06:32:51",
                "to": "01-01-1980 06:39:51",
                "include_lower": true,
                "include_upper": true,
                "boost": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

could someone tell me what is wrong with my query or mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your date field is a sub-field called `startTime.raw` you need to use it in your `range` query

```
      {
        "range": {
          "startTime.raw": {                        <----- change this
            "from": "01-01-1980 06:32:51",
            "to": "01-01-1980 06:39:51",
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true,
            "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Val. If i want to rename startTime.raw, do i need to create an alias.

Comment: Yes, you can create a [field alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/alias.html) that points to `startTime.raw`